# Issue about concurrently executing Spock integration tests of gradle project in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, parallel-processing, integration, spock

I'm working on a task to reduce the execution time of integration tests of a Gradle web project. these tests are written in Spock framework. I'm now trying to use the parallel execution feature provided by Spock 2.0 and I can successfully run some tests concurrently using intellij on my machine and the execution time reduces by 45%. but when I try to run these test using gradle command line or push them on jenkins pipeline, I don't see too much time reduction as I see on my machine, actually the duration of individual test file and the entire build time increase when I enable the parallel execution feature. so my question is what I missed or did incorrectly during the parallelization process? thanks a lot!

### build.gradle.kts

```
    plugins {
    id("com.sap.upscale")
    id("groovy")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version ("2.4.3")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version ("1.0.11.RELEASE")
    id("jacoco")
}

group = "com.sap.upscale"

springBoot {
    mainClass.value("com.hybris.caas.product.ProductContentApplication")
}

// compile dependencies versions
val pbBomVersion: String by extra
val caasStartersBomVersion: String by extra

// override springboot bom dependencies and spring-cloud-dependencies, for example: ext["groovy.version"] = "2.5.3"
// https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml
// https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/blob/master/spring-cloud-dependencies/pom.xml
// https://<Github URL>/CaaS20/pb-dependencies-bom/blob/master/pom.xml

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.sap.upscale:upscale-pb-dependencies-bom:${pbBomVersion}")
        mavenBom("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-dependencies:${caasStartersBomVersion}")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude("org.hibernate", "hibernate-entitymanager")
    }
    implementation("org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("com.github.fge:json-patch")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-error-handling")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-logging") {
        exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
    }
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-swagger")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-multitenant") {
        exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
    }
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-kafka")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-data")
    implementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-client")
    implementation("org.zalando:logbook-spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava")
    implementation("io.pivotal.cfenv:java-cfenv-boot")
    implementation("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc")
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa")
    annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    implementation("io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra")
    implementation("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine")
    implementation("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path")

    compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    testImplementation("com.sap.caas:caas-spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine")
    testImplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework","spock-spring", "2.0-M5-groovy-2.5")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework", "spock-core", "2.0-M5-groovy-2.5")
    testImplementation("org.awaitility:awaitility")
    testImplementation("org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
}

configurations.all {
    exclude("com.zaxxer", "HikariCP")
    exclude(group = "com.vaadin.external.google", module = "android-json")
}

tasks.compileJava {
    sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDir("build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java")
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor.get().asFileTree
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(mutableListOf("-processor", "lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider\$AnnotationProcessor,com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor", "-parameters"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    filter {
        excludeTestsMatching("db.migration.*")
    }
}
```

### SpockConfig.groovy

```
runner {
    parallel {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

### Console Output

```
10:32:44  Push event to branch feature/CAAS-29844
10:32:44  Checking out git git@<Github URL>:upscale-montreal/pb-devops.git into /jenkinsdata/product-content/feature%2FCAAS-29844/workspace@script to read jenkins/Jenkinsfile
10:32:44  Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
10:32:44  The recommended git tool is: NONE
10:32:44  using credential caaspipeline
10:32:44   > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /jenkinsdata/product-content/feature%2FCAAS-29844/workspace@script/.git # timeout=10
10:32:44  Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
10:32:44   > git config remote.pb-devops.url git@<Github URL>:upscale-montreal/pb-devops.git # timeout=10
10:32:44  Fetching upstream changes from git@<Github URL>:upscale-montreal/pb-devops.git
10:32:44   > git --version # timeout=10
10:32:44   > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
10:32:44  using GIT_SSH to set credentials Git credentials for https://<Github URL>
10:32:44   > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@<GitHub URL>:upscale-montreal/pb-devops.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/pb-devops/* # timeout=10
10:32:44   > git rev-parse pb-devops/master^{commit} # timeout=10
10:32:44  Checking out Revision db67af20f544dcd83ca28f1e8cbbb5faf699ceda (pb-devops/master)
10:32:44   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
10:32:44   > git checkout -f db67af20f544dcd83ca28f1e8cbbb5faf699ceda # timeout=10
10:32:44  Commit message: "Fix health check jenkinsfile"
10:32:44   > git rev-list --no-walk db67af20f544dcd83ca28f1e8cbbb5faf699ceda # timeout=10
10:32:44  Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
10:32:45  [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
10:32:45  [Pipeline] library
10:32:45  Loading library pb-pipeline-library@master
10:32:45  Attempting to resolve master from remote references...
10:32:45   > git --version # timeout=10
10:32:45   > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
10:32:45  using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials caaspipeline-credentials - Updated by Jenkins Job: 05/02/2019 14:48:23.139
10:32:45   > git ls-remote -- https://<Github URL>/upscale-montreal/pb-pipeline-library.git # timeout=10
10:32:46  Found match: refs/heads/master revision 17eea3b2d49dd89edc489880728b020eea311856
10:32:46  Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
10:32:46  The recommended git tool is: NONE
10:32:46  using credential caaspipeline-credentials
10:32:46   > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /jenkinsdata/product-content/feature%2FCAAS-29844/workspace@libs/pb-pipeline-library/.git # timeout=10
10:32:46  Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
10:32:46   > git config remote.origin.url https://<Github URL>/upscale-montreal/pb-pipeline-library.git # timeout=10
10:32:46  Fetching without tags
10:32:46  Fetching upstream changes from https://<Github URL>/upscale-montreal/pb-pipeline-library.git
10:32:46   > git --version # timeout=10
10:32:46   > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
10:32:46  using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials caaspipeline-credentials - Updated by Jenkins Job: 05/02/2019 14:48:23.139
10:32:46   > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://<Github URL>/upscale-montreal/pb-pipeline-library.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
10:32:46  Checking out Revision 17eea3b2d49dd89edc489880728b020eea311856 (master)
10:32:46   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
10:32:46   > git checkout -f 17eea3b2d49dd89edc489880728b020eea311856 # timeout=10
10:32:46  Commit message: "Update podTemplatesDefinition.groovy"
10:32:46   > git rev-list --no-walk 17eea3b2d49dd89edc489880728b020eea311856 # timeout=10
10:32:46  [Pipeline] node
10:32:46  Running on Jenkins in /jenkinsdata/product-content/feature%2FCAAS-29844/workspace
10:32:46  [Pipeline] {
10:32:46  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:46  Masking supported pattern matches of $TOKEN
10:32:46  [Pipeline] {
10:32:46  [Pipeline] sh
10:32:46  Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
10:32:46         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [TOKEN]
10:32:46         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
10:32:46  + curl -H Authorization:token **** https://<Github URL>/raw/upscale-montreal/pb-devops/master/pb-config.yml -o pb-config.yml
10:32:46    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
10:32:46                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
10:32:46  
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 24451  100 24451    0     0   179k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  179k
10:32:46  [Pipeline] sh
10:32:46  Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
10:32:46         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [TOKEN]
10:32:46         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
10:32:46  + curl -H Authorization:token **** https://<Github URL>/raw/upscale-montreal/pb-devops/master/environments.yml -o environments.yml
10:32:46    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
10:32:46                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
10:32:46  
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1852  100  1852    0     0  18520      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18520
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] readYaml
10:32:47  [Pipeline] readYaml
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // node
10:32:47  [Pipeline] echo
10:32:47  tools:: [gradle-jdk15, cf-cli, postgres, kafka, zookeeper]
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:47  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:47  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:47  [Pipeline] {
10:32:47  [Pipeline] }
10:32:47  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:48  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:48  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:48  [Pipeline] {
10:32:48  [Pipeline] }
10:32:48  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:48  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:48  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:48  [Pipeline] {
10:32:48  [Pipeline] }
10:32:48  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:48  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:48  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:48  [Pipeline] {
10:32:48  [Pipeline] }
10:32:48  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:48  [Pipeline] withCredentials
10:32:48  Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
10:32:48  [Pipeline] {
10:32:48  [Pipeline] }
10:32:48  [Pipeline] // withCredentials
10:32:48  [Pipeline] podTemplate
10:32:48  [Pipeline] {
10:32:48  [Pipeline] node
10:33:03  Still waiting to schedule task
10:33:03  ‘aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1’ is offline
10:33:06  Agent aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1 is provisioned from template aproduct-content_feature_2FCAAS-2984477-bbb63
10:33:06  ---
10:33:06  apiVersion: "v1"
10:33:06  kind: "Pod"
10:33:06  metadata:
10:33:06    annotations:
10:33:06      buildUrl: "http://gkepolarbears.jaas.svc.cluster.local:8080/job/product-content/job/feature%252FCAAS-29844/77/"
10:33:06      runUrl: "job/product-content/job/feature%252FCAAS-29844/77/"
10:33:06    labels:
10:33:06      jenkins: "gkepolarbears"
10:33:06      jenkins/label-digest: "ab46cd0350f4a54a92f3123eb07578ce97510316"
10:33:06      jenkins/label: "aproduct-content_feature_2FCAAS-2984477"
10:33:06    name: "aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1"
10:33:06  spec:
10:33:06    containers:
10:33:06    - command:
10:33:06      - "cat"
10:33:06      env:
10:33:06      - name: "GRADLE_OPTS"
10:33:06        value: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g -Dorg.gradle.project.artifactory_username=upscale\
10:33:06          \ -Dorg.gradle.project.artifactory_password=KC*P?46_Q2qe@w"
10:33:06      - name: "ARTIFACTORY_USR"
10:33:06        value: "upscale"
10:33:06      - name: "ARTIFACTORY_PSW"
10:33:06        value: "KC*P?46_Q2qe@w"
10:33:06      - name: "BRANCH_NAME"
10:33:06        value: "feature/CAAS-29844"
10:33:06      image: "<Docker URL>:65098/caas/gradle:7.0.0-jdk15"
10:33:06      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
10:33:06      name: "gradle"
10:33:06      resources:
10:33:06        limits: {}
10:33:06        requests: {}
10:33:06      tty: true
10:33:06      volumeMounts:
10:33:06      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06        name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06        readOnly: false
10:33:06      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06    - image: "wurstmeister/zookeeper"
10:33:06      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
10:33:06      name: "zookeeper"
10:33:06      resources:
10:33:06        limits: {}
10:33:06        requests: {}
10:33:06      tty: true
10:33:06      volumeMounts:
10:33:06      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06        name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06        readOnly: false
10:33:06      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06    - image: "<Docker URL>:65098/caas/cf-cli:latest"
10:33:06      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
10:33:06      name: "cf-cli"
10:33:06      resources:
10:33:06        limits: {}
10:33:06        requests: {}
10:33:06      tty: true
10:33:06      volumeMounts:
10:33:06      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06        name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06        readOnly: false
10:33:06      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06    - env:
10:33:06      - name: "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT"
10:33:06        value: "9092"
10:33:06      - name: "KAFKA_BROKER_ID"
10:33:06        value: "999"
10:33:06      - name: "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME"
10:33:06        value: "localhost"
10:33:06      - name: "KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT"
10:33:06        value: "localhost:2181"
10:33:06      image: "wurstmeister/kafka:1.1.0"
10:33:06      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
10:33:06      name: "kafka"
10:33:06      resources:
10:33:06        limits: {}
10:33:06        requests: {}
10:33:06      tty: true
10:33:06      volumeMounts:
10:33:06      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06        name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06        readOnly: false
10:33:06      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06    - args:
10:33:06      - "********"
10:33:06      - "aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1"
10:33:06      env:
10:33:06      - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
10:33:06        value: "********"
10:33:06      - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
10:33:06        value: "aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1"
10:33:06      - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
10:33:06        value: "aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1"
10:33:06      - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
10:33:06        value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06      - name: "JENKINS_URL"
10:33:06        value: "http://gkepolarbears.jaas.svc.cluster.local:8080/"
10:33:06      image: "<Docker URL>:50001/sap-production/jnlp-alpine:3.26.1-sap-02"
10:33:06      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
10:33:06      name: "jnlp"
10:33:06      resources:
10:33:06        limits: {}
10:33:06        requests: {}
10:33:06      tty: false
10:33:06      volumeMounts:
10:33:06      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06        name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06        readOnly: false
10:33:06      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06    - env:
10:33:06      - name: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD"
10:33:06        value: "postgres"
10:33:06      image: "<Docker URL>:65098/caas/postgres:9.6.4"
10:33:06      imagePullPolicy: "Always"
10:33:06      name: "postgres"
10:33:06      resources:
10:33:06        limits: {}
10:33:06        requests: {}
10:33:06      tty: true
10:33:06      volumeMounts:
10:33:06      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06        name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06        readOnly: false
10:33:06      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
10:33:06    hostNetwork: false
10:33:06    nodeSelector:
10:33:06      kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
10:33:06    restartPolicy: "Never"
10:33:06    volumes:
10:33:06    - emptyDir:
10:33:06        medium: ""
10:33:06      name: "workspace-volume"
10:33:06  
10:33:10  Running on aproduct-content-feature-2fcaas-2984477-bbb63-nrkf1 in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/oduct-content_feature_CAAS-29844
10:33:10  [Pipeline] {
10:33:10  [Pipeline] milestone
10:33:10  Trying to pass milestone 0
10:33:10  [Pipeline] stage
10:33:10  [Pipeline] { (checkout)
10:33:10 14:33:10  Connecting to https://<GitHub URL>/api/v3 using caaspipeline/****** (caaspipeline-credentials - Updated by Jenkins Job: 05/02/2019 14:48:23.139)
10:33:11  [Pipeline] checkout
10:33:11  The recommended git tool is: git
10:33:14  using credential caaspipeline-credentials
10:33:14  Cloning the remote Git repository
10:33:14  Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
10:33:14  Cloning repository https://<GitHub URL>/CaaS20/product-content.git
10:33:14   > git init /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/oduct-content_feature_CAAS-29844 # timeout=10
10:33:14  Fetching upstream changes from https://<GitHub URL>/CaaS20/product-content.git
10:33:14   > git --version # timeout=10
10:33:14   > git --version # 'git version 2.18.0'
10:33:14  using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials caaspipeline-credentials - Updated by Jenkins Job: 05/02/2019 14:48:23.139
10:33:14   > git fetch --no-tags --progress -- https://<GitHub URL>/CaaS20/product-content.git +refs/heads/feature/CAAS-29844:refs/remotes/origin/feature/CAAS-29844 # timeout=10
10:33:24  Avoid second fetch
10:33:24  Checking out Revision 93c4c3e517fd417e069eb807512c8a2ed907925c (feature/CAAS-29844)
10:33:24   > git config remote.origin.url https://<GitHub URL>/CaaS20/product-content.git # timeout=10
10:33:24   > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/feature/CAAS-29844:refs/remotes/origin/feature/CAAS-29844 # timeout=10
10:33:24   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
10:33:24   > git checkout -f 93c4c3e517fd417e069eb807512c8a2ed907925c # timeout=10
10:33:25  Commit message: "turn on parallel execution"
10:33:25   > git rev-list --no-walk 0171225d079919654e3c85bc49b7fba67f075a62 # timeout=10
10:33:26  [Pipeline] readFile
10:33:26  [Pipeline] }
10:33:26  [Pipeline] // stage
10:33:26  [Pipeline] echo
10:33:26  Project Configuration :: [name:product-content, displayName:Product Content, documentation:*More information*\n<https://help.sap.com/viewer/DRAFT/175bd65ec40b459d84c7d55d5d6d0f64/DEV/en-US/ebed7bb976d041f79572f210ba426f74.html|Product Content @ SAP Help Portal>, openApi:<https://product-content-caas2-sap-test.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com|OpenAPI Specification in *Test* Environment>, githubUrl:git@<GitHub URL>:CaaS20/product-content.git, deployable:true, healthcheck:true, enableGlobalJenkinsfile:true, slackChannel:#upscale-montreal-private, tools:[gradle-jdk15, cf-cli, postgres, kafka, zookeeper, jnlp], useDefaultManifest:true, deployConfig:[instances:2, memory:1G, services:[caas2-postgresql, caas2-xsuaa, caas2-applogs, caas2-auditlog, caas2-kafka-intelligence, caas2-dynatrace]], fortify:[command:gradle -PsecurityCompliance delombok compileJava copyDependencies, source:build/delombok src/main/resources build/generated/source/apt/main, classpath:build/dependencies/*.jar:build/classes, exclude:build/delombok/com/hybris/caas/product/service/dto:build/delombok/com/hybris/caas/product/persistence/entity/*.java:build/delombok/com/hybris/caas/product/persistence/entity/audit]]
10:33:26  [Pipeline] readFile
10:33:26  [Pipeline] container
10:33:26  [Pipeline] {
10:33:26  [Pipeline] sh
10:33:27  + echo Probe to make sure postgres container is up and running, otherwise fail the build right away
10:33:27  Probe to make sure postgres container is up and running, otherwise fail the build right away
10:33:27  [Pipeline] }
10:33:27  [Pipeline] // container
10:33:27  [Pipeline] container
10:33:27  [Pipeline] {
10:33:27  [Pipeline] stage
10:33:27  [Pipeline] { (build)
10:33:27  [Pipeline] sh
10:33:28  + gradle clean build
10:33:29  
10:33:29  Welcome to Gradle 7.0!
10:33:29  
10:33:29  Here are the highlights of this release:
10:33:29   - File system watching enabled by default
10:33:29   - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
10:33:29   - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
10:33:29   - Dependency catalog feature preview
10:33:29  
10:33:29  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html
10:33:29  
10:33:30  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
10:33:32  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
10:34:18  > Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
10:34:37  
10:34:37  > Task :compileJava
10:34:37  /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/oduct-content_feature_CAAS-29844/src/main/java/com/hybris/caas/product/service/dto/product/ProductQueryObject.java:58: warning: @Builder will ignore the initializing expression entirely. If you want the initializing expression to serve as default, add @Builder.Default. If it is not supposed to be settable during building, make the field final.
10:34:37    private boolean valid = true;
......                                                              
10:34:43  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
10:34:43  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
10:34:43  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
10:34:43  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
10:34:43  50 warnings
10:34:48  
10:34:48  > Task :compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
10:34:48  > Task :processResources
10:34:48  > Task :classes
10:34:49  > Task :bootJarMainClassName
10:34:51  > Task :bootJar
10:34:51  > Task :jar SKIPPED
10:34:51  > Task :assemble
10:35:09  
10:35:09  > Task :compileTestJava
10:35:09  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
10:35:09  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
10:35:09  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
10:35:09  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
10:35:36  
10:35:36  > Task :compileTestGroovy
10:35:36  > Task :processTestResources
10:35:36  > Task :testClasses
10:35:48  
10:35:48  > Task :test
10:35:48  WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
10:35:48  WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1 (file:/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.14/f0a005fb21e7bd9b7ebf04cd2ecda0fc8f3be59d/groovy-2.5.14.jar) to constructor java.math.BigDecimal(java.math.BigInteger,long,int,int)
10:35:48  WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1
10:35:48  WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
10:35:48  WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
10:36:15  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
10:42:07  
10:42:07  > Task :check
10:42:07  > Task :build
10:42:07  
10:42:07  BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8m 30s
10:42:07  9 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 1 up-to-date
10:42:07  [Pipeline] junit
10:42:07  Recording test results
10:42:10  [Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
10:42:10  [Pipeline] }
10:42:10  [Pipeline] // stage
10:42:10  [Pipeline] }
10:42:10  [Pipeline] // container
10:42:10  [Pipeline] }
10:42:10  [Pipeline] // node
10:42:10  [Pipeline] }
10:42:10  [Pipeline] // podTemplate
10:42:10  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
10:42:11  
10:42:11  GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result
10:42:11  
10:42:11  Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Without seeing you build it is hard to say what is wrong. Do I understand you correctly that, you don't see any improvements when you run the tests on your machine using gradle? Do you already use gradle parallel execution features, i.e. `--parallel` and `maxParallelForks` ?

Comment: Yes, I don’t see obvious performance improvement when using gradle command line on my machine and yes I try the —parallel and set maxParallelForks in build.gradle.kts, and none of them works, I’m wondering if it needs to configure something in gradle configuration? As for now I doubt the gradle really recognizes the parallelization enabled by Spock configuration.

Comment: How many cores does you CI system have?

Comment: I have no idea how many cores does the CI system have, but this project is a commercial product, so I think the CI server should have multiple core.

Comment: btw, my laptop has multicore but I also don't see any performance improvement when building project with gradle command line.

Comment: Just to make sure that Spock actually finds the config file, when building with gradle, try writing `throw new RuntimeException("test")` at the start of the config.

Comment: already confirmed that spock parallel execution feature is executed on my machine, but the performance measured by gradle build time makes no difference with the build time in sequential execution whereas the parallel execution time measured by intellij is reduced by 45% than the sequential execution time. I can visually observe the speed up when the tests are executed in parallel, so frustrated!